# How can I get the error message if I see a yellow triangle on the Azure roles folder in vs2012?

Tags: visual-studio, azure

I've been hand editing Azure cloud .cscfg and the .csdef file after a painful merge. I believe I have everything right and the solution builds with no errors or warnings. Nothing appears in the output tab during the build. I have a number of Azure roles and configuration files and I know they all need to match.

However, I see a yellow triangle on the Azure roles folder in Visual Studio 2012. How can I find out my configuration error?

Comment: This usually means that you have a variable in one file (either a `.cscfg` or a `.csdef`) but not all of the others. Make sure these are **exactly** the same list of variables. Otherwise, post the files (with dummy values, if necessary) and we should be able to spot the problem for you.

Answer (score 3):

As Jaxidian commented, the solution was to diff all 8 .cscfg files against a selected master and make sure that all the   tags inside the  tag were present.

If you are trying to configure remote desktop, all the values for all the remote desktop tags need to be identical.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was either

```
<ServiceConfiguration serviceName="...
```

or ...

```
  <Role name="...
```

being invalid (set to another/incorrect service name/role).